# Why does staticMetaObject.className() return the class name of the parent class?

Tags: c++, classname, metaobject

I have a class 'Default' derived from a class 'Units' and when I do:

```
Default::staticMetaObject.className())
```

it returns `Units` instead of `Default`. Why is that? How can I fix this?

Comment: This usually happens when you forget to put `Q_OBJECT` into the derived class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turning my comment into an answer.

This usually happens when you forget to put the macro `Q_OBJECT` into the derived class.

From the point of view of Qt's meta-type system, that class is then indistinguishable from its parent class (that is, from the nearest parent class which does have `Q_OBJECT` inside).